# Basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ with an almost complex structure

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry, almost-complex

The question itself is nothing but linear algebra:

Let $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ be n linearly independent vectors (not necessarily orthogonal) in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and $J^2=-1$ is the almost complex structure, we want to show that $\{x_1,\cdots, x_n, Jx_1,\cdots, Jx_{n}\}$ span $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

To check that they are linearly independent, we assume:\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_i a_ix_i+\sum_j b_jJx_j=0 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Act $J$ on both side, we have:\begin{equation}
\sum_i a_i Jx_i-\sum_jb_jx_j=0
\end{equation}

Then I saw somebody concluded right away the following which I can not figure out why:
\begin{equation}
\sum_i (a_i^2+b_i^2)x_i=0
\end{equation}

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hint: What do we know about linear combinations of basis vectors?

Comment: Hi Ben, I'm not sure if I can connect your hint to my question. My question is how to get from the two equation I listed to $\sum_i (a_i^2+b_i^2)x_i=0$. If this is your intended answer, could you please add more detail? Thanks!

Comment: From what you wrote, it has nothing to do with the complex structure. If $\sum_i a_ie_i=0$ in a vector space where the $a_i$ are scalars and the $e_i$ form a basis (in particular, are linearly independent), then what do we know about the $a_i$?

Comment: As I said in the beginning, this is indeed a linear algebra problem. And for your hint, we both know for sure that they are all 0. What I don't understand here is, why $\{\sum_i (a_i^2+b_i^2)x_i=0\}$. Thanks for your answer Ben.

Comment: I'm hesitating to poste an answer since I'm not entirely sure if what you are asking is really what you intend to ask. If the first equation holds, then the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are zero and so each of the $(a_i^2+b_i^2)$ vanishes too.

Comment: Notice that in the first two equation, there are $Jx_i$ terms, which we don't know yet if they are linearly independent and that's what I'm asking.

Comment: If the $x_i$ together with the $Jx_i$, $i=1,2,\dots,n$, span an $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ then they constitute a basis and hence are linearly independent

Comment: I edited the problem a little bit, maybe that's more clear.

Comment: That's true, but why do they span $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$?

Comment: I can see how it's done if $n=1$, but I don't think it generalises so easily. You could try multiplying the first equation by $\sum_i a_i$ and subtract the product of the second and $\sum_i b_i$, but this will not work if $n>1$, does it?

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood your answer... The origin of this question is in the following [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJi73A6rfQAhUsxYMKHTOCBckQFggiMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.195.6462%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AFQjCNHxsCQR5KTy_OKnrxUPzMPqL6NMVw&sig2=m05-zGwJpnDcYoWc2lrkMQ) page 533. Thanks Ben!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But it's not true.  That is, not as stated.  If you take just any old $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ that is.  Consider $\mathbb R^4$, and pick some $x_1$ and for $x_2$ pick $J x_1$, then you only span a 2 dimensional subspace still.  So you definitely want $\operatorname{span} \{ x_1,\ldots,x_n \} \cap \operatorname{span} \{ J x_1, \ldots, J x_n \}$ to be trivial, otherwise what you are saying is simply not true.  But then this follows by dimension, since $J$ had better be invertible and so it preserves dimensions of subspaces.

The idea is that you need to pick a so-called maximally totally-real linear subspace.  If your initial subspace $X$, the span of the $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, has any complex structure, then the span of $X$ and $JX$ is not everything.

Comment: Thank you so much Jiri, I see your point. I guess the orthogonal basis in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ will do the job. Moreover, the equality I mentioned will follow by an inner product argument. Thanks again for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, choose any $x_1 \neq 0$. Then $x_1$ and $Jx_1$ are linearly independent since otherwise $J$ has a real eigenvalue. Next, choose
$$
  x_2 \not\in \mathop{\mathrm{span}}\{x_1,Jx_1\}.
$$
Then $x_1$, $x_2$, $Jx_1$, $Jx_2$ are linearly independent since otherwise $V = \mathop{\mathrm{span}}\{x_1,x_2,Jx_1\}$ is invariant for $J$ and then $J|_V$ must have a real eigenvalue $\lambda$ since $\dim V = 3$. Then $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue for $J$, which is a contradiction.

Proceeding in this way, you find a basis of the form $x_1$, $\dots$, $x_n$, $Jx_1$, $\dots$, $Jx_n$.